# Can I use string formatting while querying a database in python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have been learning `sqlite3` in python and I was wondering if I could use string formatting to edit the database or query it.

e.g. - `SELECT %s FROM (table_name) where %` can be the users input stored in a variable?

I tried it but it doesn't work so can someone please give me a working example.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Guys i tried this:

```
dursor = conn.execute("SELECT id FROM books")
# this helps find the correct id for storing in the database
for i in dursor:
lis.append(i[0])
command = """INSERT INTO books VALUES ({0}, {name}, {author})""".format(lis[-1] + 1, name=client_name, author = client_author)
```

and then

```
conn.execute(command)
```

but it returns no such column (name)

when i tried the same query in khan academy sql it worked why not here?

Comment: Thanks guys but i still dont get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place question mark on your query string and pass the parameters from user input while calling the .execute() as a tuple.

Though i don't believe you are using it in a production. If it is the case than first take the data from user, sanitize it and see if you really want to let the user do what he actually wants to do.

Hope this helps:

```
param1 = sys.argv[1]
param2 = sys.argv[2] 
query = "SELECT ? FROM (table_name) where id = ?"
cursor.execute(query, (param1,param2))
```

Comment: Thanks it worked and im just using it for learning not for production :)

Comment: If it helps and serves your purpose, then please accept the answer by clicking the big tick mark on the left of the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if you can do it in sqlite3 but I'd be looking for any alternative method if I were you.  Are you REALLY wanting to allow the user to be able to actually alter your SQL on the fly? That is a potentially huge security hole you'd be creating.

e.g. user can essentially alter...

```
select ? from innocentTable
```

...to...

```
select * from tblUser -- from innocentTable
```

...and trawl your entire user table, just takes a bit of guess work to come up with the object names.

I'd suggest you read up on SQL Injection Attacks then look for an alternative way to achieve what you've suggested.